# New collators not producing blocks

Tags: parachain-collator

I'm locally testing adding a new collator to two existing collators.

I managed to:

- set the aura key,

  - `ext.session.setKeys` to set public key
  - `rpc.author.insertKeys` to set private key
- add it to the `Invulnerables` list and
- let a new session start

I can see that `session.queuedKeys` storage has all of three collators' keys included but only the first two (already existing ones) are producing blocks.

Is there some steps I'm missing? I'm using the `polkadot:v0.9.19` image for relay chain.

Edit: some more details given

Comment: The steps LGTM. How did you set the key? Is the key correct?

Comment: @AurevoirXavier thanks for the comment. I made `session.setKey` extrinsic using the collator account -> then `author.insertKeys` rpc call to set the private key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session.queuedkeys` is about the keys that will be set in the next session. So, not in the current session.

Comment: Thanks @bkchr. I'll check the next session then!

Comment: Yep confirmed that (1) waiting for the next (second) session and (2) restarting node (in my case docker container) worked. Thank you so much!